# How to use Jackson Package in this scenario?

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson2

Hi I have a Json like follows:

```
A {
    B {
        C [{
            x1:x2,
            y1:y2
          }]
       }
  }
```

Now my requirement is to convert the A, B, C to camelCase notation(as required) which I did by using @JsonProperty and getter and setter methods for the respective POJO class.

Finally, my output is as follows:

```
a {
    b {
        c [{
            x1:x2,
            y1:y2
          }]
       }
  }
```

Now I want to add a new empty object like d between b and c.

Can you please help me in appending a new empty JSON object.

The required output should be something like this:

```
a {
    b {
       d {
          c [{
            x1:x2,
            y1:y2
          }]
       }
     }
  }
```

Json :

```
"Skills" : {
  "SkillSet" : [ 
    {
        "Skill" : "Management"
    },
    {
        "Skill" : "IT"
    }, 
  ]
}
```

I need something like this:

```
"skills" : {
  "mainSkills" {
     "skillSet" : [ 
       {
        "Skill" : "Management"
       },
       {
        "Skill" : "IT"
       }, 
     ]
   }
}
```

I'm done with converting the camelCase but I need to insert the new object "mainSkills".

Comment: Can you please post a **valid** JSON?

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin Updated the JSON.

Comment: Still not a valid JSON though.

Comment: Map your source JSON to Java classes (let's call them A). Map your target JSON to Java classes (let's call them B). Parse your source JSON to A, transform A to B, and write B as JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will give you the expected output:

```java
String json = "{\n" +
              "  \"skills\": {\n" +
              "    \"skillSet\": [\n" +
              "      {\n" +
              "        \"skill\": \"Management\"\n" +
              "      },\n" +
              "      {\n" +
              "        \"skill\": \"IT\"\n" +
              "      }\n" +
              "    ]\n" +
              "  }\n" +
              "}";

// Create ObjectMapper instance to parse the JSON
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

// Parse the JSON into the Jackson tree model
JsonNode tree = mapper.readTree(json);

// Store a reference to the "skills" node
JsonNode skills = tree.get("skills");

// Store a reference to the "skillsSet" node
JsonNode skillSet = skills.get("skillSet");

// Remove the "skillsSet" node from the tree
((ObjectNode) skills).remove("skillSet");

// Create the "skillSet" node under "mainSkills" 
// and sets it under the "skills" node
((ObjectNode) skills).set("mainSkills", 
        mapper.createObjectNode().set("skillSet", skillSet));

// Write the tree as a JSON string using the default pretty printer
String newJson = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(tree);
```

---

If you don't want to manipulate the JSON as demonstrated above, follow the [JB Nizet approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45709817/how-to-use-jackson-package-in-this-scenario/45713749#comment78385442_45709817).

Comment: Thank you so much. It is working as expected...All I need to learn about the code which you did step by step.

Comment: @Pavan I added comments to my code to make it clear.